# Elements not displaying properly on older generation iPads?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, display

I'm having a few issues with certain elements not displaying on old generation iPads. All of these issues I believe are unique to the 1st generation iPad, as it displays as it should on newer generations/desktop. I have fixed a few, mostly involving vh elements and parallax classes.

The problems I am experiencing are as follows:

1 - With the nav bar, when opened the links do not appear. I'm not sure if this is an issues with how the iPad reads the JavaScript, as it works perfectly fine on all other devices.

2 - I also have Google Maps iFrames on the home page and the contact page, this is not displaying at all and is just a blank space.

3 - On the home page, the top background photo does not display at all.

4 - On all other pages, there are background photos at the top with text inside, these are displaying but are not displaying properly.

Here's the link to the website: www.bodytone.ca
I understand the code is a bit of a mess right now, I still have to go through it all and fix it up.

Comment: What version of what browser is causing you trouble with iPad?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at number 3 and I believe the image is not showing due to the max image size limits on ipad 1.

https://ipadportfolioapp.com/limits.html

Your image is 2039x2065 whereas the limit in size is 2048px on either dimension.

Tried looking at number 1, it appears they don't work on ipad 2 either, I have been testing on browserstack. I don't know but I wondered if changing

```
.overlay-content {
    position: absolute;
}
```

would help, just a guess.My css isn't the best.